# How do I calculate the measurements of a hand using scikit-image?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I am trying my hand at image processing and my goal is to output the measurements of a human hand given an image of a human hand as the input. My current thought process is to include a quarter in the image to provide a reference value. Therefore, my input looks like this:

[image: hand-image]

I am currently using scikit-image for image processing, and my code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

from skimage import data
from skimage.filter import threshold_otsu
from skimage.segmentation import clear_border
from skimage.morphology import label, closing, square
from skimage.measure import regionprops
from skimage.color import label2rgb
from skimage import io, color


#image = data.coins()[50:-50, 50:-50]
filename = io.imread("hand2.JPG")
image = color.rgb2gray(filename)

# apply threshold
thresh = threshold_otsu(image)
bw = closing(image > thresh, square(3))

# remove artifacts connected to image border
cleared = bw.copy()
#clear_border(cleared)

# label image regions
label_image = label(cleared)
borders = np.logical_xor(bw, cleared)
label_image[borders] = -1
image_label_overlay = label2rgb(label_image, image=image)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=1, figsize=(12, 12))
ax.imshow(image_label_overlay)

for region in regionprops(label_image):

    # skip small images
    if region.area < 1000:
        continue

    print "Perimeter: "
    print region.perimeter
    print "Area: "
    print region.area
    print ""

    # draw rectangle around segments
    minr, minc, maxr, maxc = region.bbox
    rect = mpatches.Rectangle((minc, minr), maxc - minc, maxr - minr,
                              fill=False, edgecolor='red', linewidth=2)
    ax.add_patch(rect)

plt.show()
```

I am able to segment my image into regions, but I don't know how to convert my hand segment into measurements for the individual fingers and width of the hand. I think I'm close, I just don't quite know how to proceed!

**EDIT: Maybe I should be using opencv for this?**

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't clear exactly what you wanted as output, but here is my best guess.  I used the SLIC segmentation algorithm to identify regions in the image.  Based on their region properties (area), I choose the largest two (hand and coin) and display them, along with their principal axes.

[image: Output of hand/coin segmentation]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

from skimage import io, segmentation, measure, color

image = io.imread("hand2.JPG")

label_image = segmentation.slic(image, n_segments=2)
label_image = measure.label(label_image)

regions = measure.regionprops(label_image)
areas = [r.area for r in regions]
ix = np.argsort(areas)

hand = regions[ix[-1]]
coin = regions[ix[-2]]

selected_labels = np.zeros_like(image[..., 0], dtype=np.uint8)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=1, figsize=(12, 12))

for n, region in enumerate([hand, coin]):
    selected_labels[region.coords[:, 0], region.coords[:, 1]] = n + 2

    y0, x0 = region.centroid
    orientation = region.orientation

    x1 = x0 + math.cos(orientation) * 0.5 * region.major_axis_length
    y1 = y0 - math.sin(orientation) * 0.5 * region.major_axis_length
    x2 = x0 - math.sin(orientation) * 0.5 * region.minor_axis_length
    y2 = y0 - math.cos(orientation) * 0.5 * region.minor_axis_length

    ax.plot((x0, x1), (y0, y1), '-r', linewidth=2.5)
    ax.plot((x0, x2), (y0, y2), '-r', linewidth=2.5)
    ax.plot(x0, y0, '.g', markersize=15)

image_label_overlay = color.label2rgb(selected_labels, image=image, bg_label=0)
ax.imshow(image_label_overlay, cmap='gray')
ax.axis('image')
plt.show()
```